# Filter [struts2]: Could not find required filter class - org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.class

Tags: struts2, websphere-8

We are upgrading Web application from struts 2.3.16 to 2.5.13. We are using Web sphere application server(WAS 8.5) to run and IDE is RAD.

I have added all required JAR files but I am getting this error

```
Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [struts2]: Could not find required filter class - org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.class
```

when i checked new Struts-core-2.5.13 it does not contain `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.class`

I have made the filter changes in `web.xml` as below:

```
<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
```

Answer (score 2):

The filter `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` doesn't exist in Struts 2.5.x.

You should use `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`

For more information see

> #### [Changed filter package in Struts >= 2.5](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/web-xml.html#changed-filter-package-in-struts--25)
>
> ```
>  As from Struts 2.5 all filters were moved to top package, see example:
>
> <web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"> <filter> <filter-name>struts2</filter-name> <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: But I am using the samething

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<display-name>Struts Blank</display-name>

 <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

Comment: Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [struts2]: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter was found, but is corrupt:

Comment: @pallavipatil That's an entirely different issue.

Comment: @pallavipatil If you have another question, you should mark this as accepted and ask a new one. You can reference a link to the old question if you need.

Comment: Re-read the OP question. It is about `FilterDispatcher` not about `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`.

Comment: `FilterDispatcher` -> `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` -> `Changed filter package in Struts >= 2.5`.